# Pre populate values in dropdown in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to populate and select the option in my view.

I am able to get the value from my model in my view.

edite.blade.php template

```
<select id="province" type="text" class="form-control" name="province">
<option value="">Province</option>
<option value="provinceO1">Option 1</option>
<option value="provinceO2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

How can i select an option with value I have from my model.

```
{{$edit_student_data->province}} // this help me to get value from DB
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understood your question, you just have to mark that option as `selected`. Something like below

```
<select id="province" type="text" class="form-control" name="province">
    <option value="">Province</option>
    <option value="provinceO1" {{ "provinceO1" == $edit_student_data->province ? 'selected' : '' }}>Option 1</option>
    <option value="provinceO2" {{ "provinceO2" == $edit_student_data->province ? 'selected' : '' }}>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Following will be more nice solution

```
<select id="province" type="text" class="form-control" name="province">
    <option value="">Province</option>

    @foreach(['provinceO1', 'provinceO2'] as $province)    
    <option value="{{ $province }}" {{ $province == $edit_student_data->province ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $province }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```